# Reinforcement Learning: Formally, does an exponentially decaying epsilon satisfy GLIE?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, probability, theory, learning

I am aware that exponentially decaying exploration constants (epsilon) are used practically. Formally, though, do they satisfy the GLIE condition?

Specifically, relating this to the Borel-Cantelli lemma from probability theory, it seems that if an action is selected with an exponentially decaying probability, then the probability of it being selected infinitely often would be zero, thus breaking the first GLIE condition.

Practically, if so, would this matter?